# qsort does not make any changes to the integer array

Tags: c++, c++14, qsort

I'm using qsort to sort an array of integers. But qsort is not making any changes in the array. My compare function is as follows:

```
int mycomp(const void *a, const void *b){
int *a1 = (int*)a;
int *b1 = (int*)b;

if ( a1 <  b1 ) 
    return -1;
else if ( a1 == b1 ) 
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
}
```

The array contains:

```
pos[M] = {40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 5, 10, 15, 20, 15, 30, 35};
```

And I called qsort as:

```
qsort(pos, M, sizeof(int), mycomp);
```

The output is the exact same array. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You tagged this as `C++`, `C++14`, etc., so why are you using qsort in a C++ program?  **Stay away from using qsort in a C++ program** -- instead use `std::sort`.  It is as simple as. `std::sort(std::begin(pos), std::end(pos));`

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compare pointer not values.

**fix:**

```
int a1 = *(int*)a;
int b1 = *(int*)b;
```